# What is the difference between action and action.value in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, forms

There is a form like the one mentioned below.

```
<form  name="abc" action="../xyz.jsp" onsubmit="return efg()"></form>
```

Now in the javascript, if we set the action.value to something else. Say as described below.

```
function efg(){
    document.abc.action.value="pqr.jsp";
    return true
}
```

The question I have now is, when the final submission happens, which jsp will the form submission direct to?

Comment: onsubmit will execute first. Try running this and have a look at what happens

Comment: Nothing will happen, your form will submit to the set `action` attribute in the html. Since `action` is a `string` you cannot set a property on it. `action.value` will just resort to being `undefined`

Comment: Why not just try it and see...? Fix the issue that Patrick pointed out, [put your code in a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/12cdnrk1/), press F12, go to *Network*, then submit the form and see where it goes.

Comment: it will submit to the form action url . in js it just set "pqr.jsp" to an undefined object variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`action` is a property that gets or sets the URL to which the form is submitted. There is no `value` property in `action`. So the value of action will remain unchanged:

```js
function efg(){
    document.abc.action.value="pqr.jsp";
    console.log(document.abc.action);
    return false;
}
```

```html
<form  name="abc" action="../xyz.jsp" onsubmit="return efg()">
<button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your effort and time. The mist is clear now.

Answer (score 0):

Your action points to where to send the form to whether a request or a url.  Usually a value indicates the value of the form that you want to send through the action.  The action.value will not return any value, just undefined.